# Automator - Renaming it without any .html extension

Tags: finder, automator, folders, macos

Can we able to rename the files without file extensions?

I did tried the following setup, But I get the filename ended with "." may be because the same folder name as file exists.

Here is my current workflow. You can see in the image that in the final step, filename "dc." That's a html file.

[image]

Comment: did you try with using `.html` instead of `html` as `find` query ?

Comment: Suresh Kumar Gondi, I've edited your question to cover only one issue. If you have another issue, then please post another question. This site works best with one question per question.

Comment: @ankii I did tried find, I have too many files in folder and sub-folder. If they are in same folder find can certainly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a *folder/directory* of the same *base name* of the *file name* does not exist at the same level as the *file* then it can be done, otherwise you cannot remove `.html` from the *file name* at the same level.

To remove the *extension* and the **.** you need to use:

- Find: **.html** in **fullname**

If the *fully qualified pathname* contains **.html** in other then the actual *file name*, then you'll have to use a **Run Shell Script** *action* instead of the **Rename Finder Items** *action*.

- **Run Shell Script** *action*:

  - Shell: `/bin/bash`
  - Pass input: **as arguments**

    ```
    for f in "$@"
    do
        [ ! -d "${f%.*}" ] || continue
        mv -n "$f" "${f%.*}"
    done
    ```

**NOTE:** As *coded*, if *folder/directory* of the same *base name* of the *file name* does exist at the same level as the *file* then nothing will happen and the *file name* will be unchanged.

---

If you need to clean up things, that is to remove trailing **.** in the *file names* from the previous renaming, do the following in **Terminal**:

```
cd /path/to/article
find . -type f -iregex '.*\.$' | for f in *; do [ ! -d "${f%.*}" ] || continue; mv -vn "$f" "${f%.*}"; done
```

Same note from above applies here as well.

Comment: Hey mate, Thanks for the help. 

In the shell command, it moves .html files the files one level down. 

This is code I used to create the .html files 

find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.html' -exec sh -c '
    d="$(dirname "$1")";
    mv "$1" "$d/../$(basename "$d").html";
    rmdir "$d";
' find-sh {} \;

To understand more about my above code workflow, here is one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236564/find-index-html-files-rename-with-folder-name-and-move-file-a-level-up

Comment: @Suresh Kumar Gondi, Not sure what your comment has to do with the current situation as shown in your OP, there is no _shell script_ in your OP. If my answer is not applicable to what you've shown in your OP then you need to edit it to be more clear.

Comment: Oops my bad. the code I gave in the comment has workflow of renaming the files with and move one level up. And the bash code in your first line.. move the files one level down.

Comment: It did, Before https://share.getcloudapp.com/WnuGm1ex and after https://share.getcloudapp.com/E0ubX6dJ (edited)

Comment: @Suresh Kumar Gondi, The linked pictures in your previous comment clarifies info in your OP that wasn't totally clear and as such I've updated my answer.

Comment: Apologies for that.  Can we have same file name with different kinds in the same level? A s one is a folder, and the other is a HTML document.

Comment: @Suresh Kumar Gondi, Within the same container there cannot be two items with the same name, regardless of there type.

Comment: Got it, Thank you so much for the help mate :) Appreciate it. You rock.

Comment: Apologies for it :) Marked it as the answer and upvoted.